# Raspberry Pi / Digital Light Intensity Photosensitive Sensors Module

Tags: python

I am using my Raspberry Pi with a digital light photosensitive module to make my "dumb" washer and dryer "smart". So for the washer machine sensor I am receiving two messages when it is finished instead of a single one. That isn't that big of a deal but I really want is it to only run the script when it senses a change. I think I might to increase my bouncetime?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
import time 
from twilio.rest import Client
def callback(channel):  
    if GPIO.input(channel):
        #print ("Washing Machine Has Finished!")
                # Your Account SID from twilio.com/console
                account_sid = "XXXXXXXXXX"
                # Your Auth Token from twilio.com/console
                auth_token  = "XXXXX"
                client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
                message = client.messages.create(
                to="+555555", 
                from_="55555",
                body="Washing Machine Has Finished")
                #print(message.sid)
        
    else:
        print ("Washing Machine Is Running!")
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
channel = 4
GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.BOTH, bouncetime=300)
GPIO.add_event_callback(channel, callback)
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: What happened when you increased your bounce time?

Comment: What exactly is your question about this?

Comment: So my question is, I only want the script to run when it senses a change on the module, I.E. A light change. Maybe I am not understanding the bouncetime ?

Comment: You can probably debounce for the whole length of a run and it'd be fine (if ridiculous)